# Peculiar behavior of margin css property

Tags: html, css, margin

The situation is:

The CSS:

```
<style>
#aux1{
    position:relative;      
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
#aux2{
    display:block;
    background-color:#F00;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:20px;
}

</style>
```

The HTML:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
    "...some content (div with height: auto)"
    <div id="aux1">
        <div id="aux2">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the margin property from aux2 acts strange as in the following image:

[image: unusual margin photo 1]

If I put overflow:hidden in aux1 the result tends to normal:

[image: unusual margin photo 2]

Why do I even need to use overflow:hidden for the margin (especially margin-top) to act normally?

Comment: it is... you are right. Although my question is on a specific case of collapsing, the parent-child div case

Comment: The duplicate question also talks about a parent-child div margin collapsing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, **margin collapsing** as in this question: [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Another question reference: [What is the point of CSS collapsing margins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069921/what-is-the-point-of-css-collapsing-margins)