# On what the margin impact

Tags: html, css, margin

I was thinking, about how the margin influence other objects?

Because when I have e.g.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div{
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

and inside I have div with `margin-top` it push `<body>` down, so the margin impact on `<html>` not on `<body>` tag, which is first container.

So the question is, how margin depend on

1. parent tag
2. siblings tags
3. floating, absolute, relative or static elements

I have readed few css tutorials, but I couldnt find specific answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers by default add a margin to the `<body>` element. One thing you haven't done in your styling is to reset this to 0:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Why this happens is a question that has been asked many times here. See: [What is the point of CSS collapsing margins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069921/what-is-the-point-of-css-collapsing-margins) and [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work).

Comment: I noticed that, but body margin is only about 20px, (I set 180px more) and the same is happening when I have wrapper div instead of body.
Anyway, collapsing margins is right answer, Thank You.