# margin increase height of parent

Tags: html, css

**Hello**, why margin bottom of child not increasing the height of parent:

```
<div class="my-container">
<div class="margin">
    Hello World
</div>
<div class="margin">
    Hello World
</div>
```

```
.my-container {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 300px;
background-color: #3873fe;
margin: auto;
}

.my-container .margin {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
    background-color: #00ff82;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image]

But if add **border for parent**, the height of parent will increased:

```
.my-container {
    border:1px solid;
}
```

[image]

So I'd like to understand why this difference?

Comment: You are not closing the `.my-container` div.

Comment: Have a google for css collapsing margins - this will explain why the bottom margin does not affect the parent div

Comment: Pete's comment is better answer when the two answers so far as it explains the actual reason.

Comment: True, @Pete found the origin of the problem I just know how to fix it, didn't know what was the original behavior. Always learning new things ! :)

Comment: Thank you pete I will check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: auto;` to the parent div.

```css
.my-container {
  overflow: auto;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #3873fe;
  margin: auto;
}

.my-container .margin {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  background-color: #00ff82;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="margin">
    Hello World
  </div>
  <div class="margin">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know the solution but I'd like to know what is the reason?!

Comment: The problem as @Pete told us is collapsing margins, you can have more information about there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069921/what-is-the-point-of-css-collapsing-margins

Comment: @MichaelNeas If my answer was the correct one you can mark it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` and `width: 100%` for my-container.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pe2szrr1/)

**CSS**

```
.my-container {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 300px;
background-color: #3873fe;
margin: auto;
}

.my-container .margin {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
    background-color: #00ff82;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```