# Why does the scale CSS transformation function not affect margin?

Tags: css, scale, margin, css-transforms

I have a div that contains several other divs and elements.

Now I want to use `transform: scale(n)`

but when I do use it, everything looks fine, except that the margins of **inner** divs are kept the same size
But 
the inner elements width are changed

[image]

---

[image]

As you can see the size of the div is cut by half...
but the margin is the same :/

For example code, you have a div inside a parent.
This child div has margin top of 100px

if I change the scale of the parent, the margin of the child stays the same but the size not. You can see that by the point the child is not moving while changing scales.

```css
.holder {
  background: pink;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

#son {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div id="son">
    dontcare
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be the same for me ... can you shrae your code

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Thanks guys added an example

Comment: updated my answer, hope it's clear now ;)

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

Transforms are relative to the [reference box](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box) which is set by the [`transform-box` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) which defaults to [`border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). The border box is bounded by the border. As a result the scale transformation will scale everything within and including the border (border, padding, content box).

## Long answer

I'm going to start my answer off with the following example:

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.scaled {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <button class="default">Button</button>
  <button class="scaled">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two buttons. Both are given 10px padding and 10px margin (as well as default browser styles). The second is scaled by a factor of 2.

In Firefox 58 the first button renders with the following properties:

[image: Screenshot of box model view in Firefox DevTools of first button]

We'll focus on the properties and values of the horizontal axis:

```
        34.7167   // Content box width
        10        // Padding left
        10        // Padding right
         7        // Border left
         7     +  // Border right
    ------------
        68.7167
    ------------

        10         // Margin left
        10         // Margin right
```

If you total everything but the margin you'll get the element width. The margin is excluded. This is due to the browser defining the element box as everything inside and including the border. This behaviour is specified by the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) rule set to `border-box`.

**So how does this play into the `scale` transform function not scaling the margin?**

Transformations occur relative to a [**reference box**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box). The reference box is defined by the [`transform-box` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) which by default has the value `border-box`. As a result the border, padding and content box dimensions will be scaled by 2 while the margin is not.

This behaviour can be observed in the second button, which is scaled:

[image: Screenshot of box model view in Firefox DevTools of second button]

Again, looking at the properties and values of the horizontal axis:

```
    34.7167 * 2  =   69.4334   // Content box width
    10      * 2  =   20        // Padding left
    10      * 2  =   20        // Padding right
     7      * 2  =   14        // Border left
     7      * 2  =   14     +  // Border right
-----------------------------
    68.7167 * 2  =  137.4334
-----------------------------

    10                         // Margin left
    10                         // Margin right
```

## Further reading

- [CSS Transforms Module Level 1 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/), specifically:

  - [The definition for the **user coordinate system** or **local coordinate system**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#local-coordinate-system)
  - [The Transform Rendering Model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-rendering)
  - [Transform reference box: the `transform-box` property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box)
- [MDN documentation on `box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
- [MDN documentation on `transform-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)

Comment: sorry but how this is related ?, it's well explained btw ... but if you check his example you will see that margin belong to a child element and not the element it self ... so the issue is why the inner margin which should be included in the transformation is not being considered

Comment: by the way check the devtools and use a very small scale and you will see that maring is also considered

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Ahh I didn't see the transform rule declared on the parent. Thanks for raising. However I believe my answer still stands because "Transformations are cumulative. That is, elements establish their local coordinate system within the coordinate system of their parent" and the local coordinate system "has its origin at the top-left of a reference box specified by the `transform-box` property." Quoted from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-rendering.

Comment: try it and see the effect :) if you scale the container of both element the inner  margin will decrease. He has two main issue check below my answer for more detail ;)

Comment: If you follow the link you'll see that `transform-box` is an experimental feature and can't be changed on older browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Your first screenshot seems to show an issue with `transform-orginin` which by default is `50% 50% 0` (the center of the element). Change it to `top left` and your element will be scaled for the top-left and thus the *margin* will decrease.

---

Concerning the code you shared, this is not related to scale but your are facing a **margin-collapsing** issue. The margin of the son is collapsed with the margin of its parent and the same thing happen until this one is collapsed with the `body` margin. In other words the margin no more belong to the scaled element.

Here is your intial code with the margin-collpasing:

```css
body {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#000 50%,transparent 0) 0 0/100% 100px;
}

.holder {
  animation:anim 3s infinite linear;
  transform-origin:top;
}

#son {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: green;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    transform:scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform:scale(0.3);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div id="son">
    dontcare
  </div>
</div>
```

And the same code if we remove the margin-collapsing by adding a small padding:

```css
body {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#000 50%,transparent 0) 0 0/100% 100px;
}

.holder {
  padding-top:1px;
  animation:anim 3s infinite linear;
  transform-origin:top;
}

#son {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: green;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    transform:scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform:scale(0.3);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div id="son">
    dontcare
  </div>
</div>
```

You can clearly see a difference between both of them. In the second example the margin is considered with the scale unlike the first one.

---

Here is some usefull links for more details:

[CSS margin terror; Margin adds space outside parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573653/css-margin-terror-margin-adds-space-outside-parent-element)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519933/8620333

[What is the point of CSS collapsing margins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069921/what-is-the-point-of-css-collapsing-margins)

https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/

Answer (score 0):

Transformations do affect the visual rendering, but have no affect on the CSS layout other than affecting overflow.

from [W3.org《The Transform Rendering Model》](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering) Standard

and demo here:

```js
console.log('getComputedStyle:height: ' + getComputedStyle(box).height);
console.log('getComputedStyle:width: ' + getComputedStyle(box).width);
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  box
</div>
```

> but when I do use it, everything looks fine, except that the margins
>   of inner divs are kept the same size But the inner elements width are
>   changed

you can use the getComputedStyle to find that the inner elements width didn't change;

Comment: @Bart that is ,the actual size is still the same as before you set，i try to find the documents

Comment: but visually they change and this is the purpose of the question ... what you meant that nothing is changing but he said that the width is changing and not the marigin so he's talking about the visual i guess

Comment: i guess he think that the transformations change the width,actually didn't,everything stay where they are and just change the visual rendering which means you thought something change like width,actually didn't

Comment: yes but we are talking about the visual width .. we all know the initial won't change ... but as you can see in his screenshot visual it changing and thus the question

Comment: of couse the visual change,,,,you set the transform: scale and then surprised by visual the change. i don't understand if there is anything to feel surprised.

Comment: he is not surprised :) he simply doesn't understand why the width changed visually and not the margin ... which is not clear by the way as for me both are changing visually.