# Why top margins are collapsing but bottom margins are not?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, clearfix

As you can see in the following demo, in `left-column`, the upper padding edge of `.clearfix-using_display-table`(yellow part) and that of `.clearfix-using_display-table p`(silver part) touch each other. However, on the lower edge, for some reason, two edges don't touch each other.

In fact, the layout of `right-column` is what I think boxes in `left-column` should be look like.

```css
.left-column,
.right-column {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150px;
}
.left-column {
  float: left;
}
.right-column {
  float: right;
}
.clearfix-using_display-table,
.clearfix-using_display-block {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 125px;
}
.clearfix-using_display-table p,
.clearfix-using_display-block p {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.clearfix-using_display-table:after,
.clearfix-using_display-block:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix-using_display-table:after {
  display: table;
}
.clearfix-using_display-block:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    <h3>Table</h3>
    <div class="clearfix-using_display-table">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <h3>Block</h3>
    <div class="clearfix-using_display-block">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess this have something to do with margin collapsing and the establishment of a new BFC, but I'm not sure. Can someone clean thinks up for me?

Comment: On a "clearfix" method based on `display:table`, vertical margins do not collapse, with `display block` they do. Src: http://cssmojo.com/the-very-latest-clearfix-reloaded/

Comment: @LGSon I've read that somewhere. However, if vertical margins do not collapse, why the grey part touches the orange part on the top edge?

Comment: Because the `p` has a bottom margin, not a top, which is the reason the 2:nd is pushed downwards

Comment: @LGSon But adding `margin-top: 1em;` for `p` does not make a difference(the code in my question has been updated)

Comment: Sorry, partly wrong by me, establish a new BFC will, add for example `overflow: auto;` to your `.clearfix-using_display-table, .clearfix-using_display-block` rule

Comment: @LGSon I'm sorry, but I really cannot understand your last comment:1. What creates a new BFC? 3. The BFC is created in which box? 3. How does the `overflow: auto;` rule contribute to this layout?

Comment: Posted an answer with links to official resources that explains what and how BFC and collapse margins work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "clearfix" with `display: table` will keep the bottom margin, `display: block` will not.

Src: http://cssmojo.com/the-very-latest-clearfix-reloaded/

*Update: Why the top margin collapse is because of no BFC is estabished on its immediate parent*

---

To make the margins not collapse, add a [*BFC*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), in this case on the `p` parent, like in below sample, by adding for example `overflow: auto`.

More to read: [*Mastering margin collapsing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

*Update: [Why doesn't a `<table>`'s margin collapse with an adjacent `<p>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136727/why-doesnt-a-tables-margin-collapse-with-an-adjacent-p)*

```css
.left-column,
.right-column {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150px;
}
.left-column {
  float: left;
}
.right-column {
  float: right;
}
.clearfix-using_display-table,
.clearfix-using_display-block {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 125px;
  overflow: auto;                      /*  establish BFC  */
}
.clearfix-using_display-table p,
.clearfix-using_display-block p {
  background-color: silver;
  width: 100px;
}
.clearfix-using_display-table:after,
.clearfix-using_display-block:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix-using_display-table:after {
  display: table;
}
.clearfix-using_display-block:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-column">
    <h3>Table</h3>
    <div class="clearfix-using_display-table">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <h3>Block</h3>
    <div class="clearfix-using_display-block">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! However, my question is about why the top margins are collapsing but bottom margins are not **when there is no BFC**...

Comment: @sunqingyao The link to http://cssmojo.com/the-very-latest-clearfix-reloaded/ explained that, that on a "clearfix" method based on `display:table`, vertical margins do not collapse, with `display block` they do.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems that while vertical margins do not collapse on the bottom, for some reason, they *do* collapse on the top. And as the title suggests, this question is intended to focus on why they collapse on the top.

Comment: @sunqingyao The 2 ways combined explain that, where the top margin collapse because there is no BFC, the bottom does not on table but does on block. Also added a new link in my answer, which might be a duplicate to this question

Comment: That's it! Clearfix is implemented by creating the pseudo element `.clearfix:after`, so it's quite reasonable that only the button margin is affected.

Comment: @sunqingyao Yepp ... kind of .. the clearfix adds an element to clear the float, the added element though, is the one that either collapse or don't collapse